# Paypal Integration in Web application

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2, paypal-ipn

The scenario is that users of web application can purchase digital items. The web application will use [Paypal Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn).

The IPN protocol consists of three steps:

1. PayPal sends your IPN listener a message that notifies you of the event
2. Your listener sends the complete unaltered message back to PayPal; the message must contain the same fields in the same order and be encoded in the same way as the original message
3. PayPal sends a single word back, which is either VERIFIED if the message originated with PayPal or INVALID if there is any discrepancy with what was originally sent.

Let's say it's `VERIFIED`, how could I know who have completed the transaction or purchased the item (user of the web application) if the user used other email address in his/her paypal? I have stored the email address of the user in `session` but what if he/she have different paypal email? Paypal email is included in IPN message.

For other details, maybe not useful, the application is written in Struts2 in Google-App-Engine.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a way to correlate the IPN data coming back with the user.  Either by asking them to provide their paypal email or using the username/password generation facility in the IPN service.  Here is a somewhat inelegant but functional approach:

- When the IPN comes in off the wire, persist the paypal generated username/password and payer_id (in perhaps the datastore).
- If you can't correlate by email, then when the user comes back to your site request that they enter the username/password generated from paypal's site *once* (just to correlate).
- Lookup the username/password and then correlate their userid from the UserService back to the payerid.

The reason to use IPN is for subscription services as you can get IPN messages when the subscription is terminated, cancelled, or when payments come in (for an account that stopped paying).

The most important thing to think about is how to correlate a user of your site back to the payer_id (or even payer_ids in some cases) that are used to pay for the services they are using.

On another note, I wouldn't use the session to store information for IPN callbacks, those actually can take a LONG time sometimes (say when the x.com conference is on and everyone is hammering paypal).

If you have a running application or a better description of the look & feel, I might be able to come up with a more elegant suggestion.  Let me know if this helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use PayPal's express checkout? This way you negotiate server2server a token and then you can check with PayPal the result of that token on user's return.
If users are buying directly from your application it's easier to implement.
And I think it'is more robust than the method you're using (I never heard of it before :D )